# Using p2.artifacts.process without updating artifacts.size

Tags: eclipse, metadata, p2

I have a p2 repo with zipped binary data wrapped in features. While creating this repo, I calculate unzipped data size and created `artifacts.xml` via **shell** script. But after signing this repo, when I rerun p2 metadata generator (using p2.artifacts.process in **ANT** script) to fix md5 checksum, it **recalculates** sizes and as those features are now zipped, it sets wrong `artifact.size` in `artifacts.xml.`

Is there any way, I can do any of following:

1. Using **p2.artifacts.process** without updating `artifacts.size`
   property?
2. Any other way to update md5 checksum without changing `artifacts.size` property?
3. Any other better way to address this problem?

Comment: the updated artifact size for your features is exactly the size of the compressed jar file. the p2.artifcats.process is zipping and updating the metadata correctly.
Why are you doing this manually with a script? The p2 task is doing the correct thing. Are you facing issues with the resulting repo?

Comment: Yes. You are right. But my features contain zipped binary data and before running p2.artifacts.process, I calculate size of unzipped data and set artifact.size property accordingly. But p2.artifacts.process resets it to size of compressed feature jar file. Because of this, I get wrong size requirement while installing this repo.

Comment: @Peter Kirschner I made a small change in my current script. I moved signing step a bit earlier and sign features before calculating its artifact.size. With this approach, For every feature, I first sign its jar then calculate its size (unzipped) and checksum and put its entry in artifacts.xml.
I then don't need to run **p2.artifacts.process**. This seems to be working fine for me so far.